# Halo 5 trying to get my Guest added to game to play coop camp

Tags: halo-5-guardians

Im trying to play coop campaign wit my friend in my room signed him in as guest  now how do i add him to fire team or whatever so me and him can play campaign coop , coop is so we both can play obviously   , but im just playing by my self every time , cant figure out how to get him in the campaihn wit me to play side by side ? Please help

Answer (score 3):

There is no split screen co-op in Halo 5. In fact, there is no split screen at all

[This decision was made to improve the fidelity of the overall game](https://www.halowaypoint.com/en-us/community/blog-posts/halo-5-guardians-your-team-is-your-weapon)

> The decision to remove split-screen support from Halo 5: Guardians was one of the most difficult ones we’ve ever had to make as a studio. We know that for many of our fans, Halo has meant playing together with friends in the same room. We all have great memories of past Halo split-screen multiplayer matches. To move Halo’s gameplay forward and deliver a true next-gen experience, tough choices had to be made. Our decision was driven by a desire for scale, fidelity and focus to ensure that we would deliver the best quality experience possible. With Halo 5 we are delivering massive scale environments, improved AI behavior, increased visual and gameplay fidelity… something that truly takes advantage of a new platform. Many of our ambitious goals for Halo 5 would be compromised in a split-screen setting and the time spent optimizing and addressing split-screen-specific issues would take focus from building other parts of the game. Game development is a balancing act of resources, time and technology, and in this case we made the tough decision to sacrifice something that’s been near and dear to us all.

Whether or not this is justified is entirely opinion, and currently highly debated.

Comment: Yeah, this would make sense if it was 360. And I see why it's highly debated.